# How to Show printer name default with php

Tags: php, printing

I want to show my default printer name with PHP script, tell me how to show..

for sample http://bagiin.com/xampp.JPG

like adobe pdf (printer name) red circle

sorry my english is bad

thank b4

iwk

Comment: Do you actually want to show what printer is attached to your server to the world ( if there is one, I haven't seen any web server with a printer attached, but who am I ....) ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this function

```
$printers = printer_list ( PRINTER_ENUM_DEFAULT );

foreach ($printers as $printer) {
    echo $printer['NAME'];
}
```

Comment: not error, but i want to take 1 name printer(only printer default), ypur code show all printer name, you can see my picture on http://http://bagiin.com/xampp.JPG see a red circle just printer default

Comment: try my updated code, based on php documentation it suppose to only work for Windows 9x. but so far this code had worked for you. So let see.

Comment: yes, i have try your new code, not working on xp , result blank page, i use xampp 1.8.1